# View PdfSharp document in a WPF control

Tags: wpf, pdfsharp

I'm using the companion [MigraDoc and PdfSharp libraries](http://www.pdfsharp.net) to generate a report.

The [PdfSharp documentation](http://www.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharpFeatures.ashx) repeatedly refers to WPF and talks about you can "draw on a PDF page as well as in a window", but I can't figure out how to view my `PdfDocument` in a viewer. All of the examples just kick the rendering off to another program by opening the documents with `Process.Start()`.

Do either of these libraries include WPF controls for viewing the documents? Ideally I'm looking for a basic document viewer control, similar to the built-in `RichTextEditor` viewer for `FlowDocuments`.

(I'm using the PdfSharp and MigraDoc libraries that are distributed through NuGet.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WPF PDF Viewer](https://wpfpdfviewer.codeplex.com/). It wraps the Adobe PDF Reader COM Component as a WPF control

Comment: This solution does not work with Adobe Reader add-on disabled in IE.

Answer (score 2):

PDF Viewer is an ActiveX control which needed to be hosted using WindowsFormHost. If you need a WPF renderer for PDR, Adobe didnt introduced it yet. You need to create it yourself and parse the PDF document.

Here are few links which will help you how to host a PDF document on your WPF window :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380019/Using-Adobe-Reader-in-a-WPF-app

http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/

Telerik has a PDF Viewer created using WPF which does the rendering of a PDF document using WPF. Its called RADPDFViewer
http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/12-02-29/introducing-pdf-viewer-for-silverlight-wpf.aspx

You have to either use one that is shipped by Adobe or you need to create it of your own just like Telerik did.

Comment: I'm in particular interested in the PdfSharp library, since that's what I'm using. They mention WPF all over the place, but no examples!

Comment: PdfSharp doesnt have a WPF previewer as of now. The previewer they have built is derived from Windows.Forms.UserControl and draws using GDI. 
http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/96133#707095

The WPF previewer also seems to be having problems. Everything is disabled here : 

http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/96133#707572